# How to create a password to open firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, passwords, password-protection

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox 15.0.1
I have some history saved in my Firefox browser.
I find it useful to have them.
But I don't want my friends or anyone to have a look at my history when they borrow my laptop.
So I want to put a password to Firefox, i.e., when someone opens Firefox, they should be prompted for a password.

How do I do this?

EDIT: No, not a guest account. I want to know how it can be done like I asked.
(I wouldn't want to logout and re-login with the guest account and give it to my friend,
Besides file privileges are totally different in guest accounts. I want my friends to have normal file privileges :) .)

Comment: Take a look at this guide: [Protect your Firefox profile](http://www.chillgeeks.com/2009/07/protect-your-firefox-profile.html)

Comment: You are _way_ too trusting of your friends.

Comment: Frankly, you're going about this the wrong way. If you don't trust people enough to use your browser session - which I totally understand, by the way - then you need to give them a seperate *computer* account, as has already been suggested. I understand that you apparently don't want to do this, but that doesn't make it the wrong answer.

Comment: Hi. Don't take me wrong. The reason why I prefer the "firefox profile" solution is because I feel that is easier than logging out and logging back in as a guest. And, the file privileges.
In the question, I ask "How to create a password to open firefox?"
While Ubuntu profiles solution would work, I wanted one like this.
Thank you everyone :D
@amiregelz, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a different profile for yourself and others

start the profile manager (run firefox with `firefox -ProfileManager`)and create a new default profile for your friends to use

with the command `firefox -P <profile>` you can specify which profile firefox should load

hide a shortcut with these arguments for your own fast startup

Answer (score 5):

A better approach would be to create a guest account or separate accounts for all users on your ubuntu machine. This way there will be separate firefox settings for everyone. (actually for all apps for that matter)

Answer (score 1):

You create a second account on the laptop (a la windows 'guest' account).

Your friends log in with that username and password and can not access your files (including the firefox profile).